# Problem Installing minted on Windows 11

Tags: errors, windows

I tried to install the `minted` package in LaTeX. I followed the instructions on https://alipourmousavi.com/blog/index.php/2018/02/08/using-minted-package-in-latex-to-format-codes/, except the part about the Python version. I don't want to remove the current version on my computer (`3.11.0rc1`), because it is tied to some other programs. This resulted in the failure of running the command `pygmentize --version`:

```
'C:\Users\remmymilkyway\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I try to compile a basic LaTeX code using `minted`, the following error occurs:

```
Cannot find Pygments style default
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: presumably pygmentize does not have a 3.11 wheel and therefore cannot be ran using a 3.11 interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Python 3.11.0rc1` is where it all goes wrong. Instead of that, just install a stable version of Python. Thanks to henry groves, the issue is solved.